# Why does $F$ being conservative guarantee that $\operatorname{curl} F = 0$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, vector-fields

Clairaut's Theorem guarantees that

> If $f$ is a function of three variables that has continuous second-order partial derivatives, then $\operatorname{curl} f = 0$. This can be confirmed by evaluating $\nabla \times \nabla f$.

Now here's where I'm lost: apparently, a consequence of this is that

> If **F** is conservative, then $\operatorname{curl}$ **F** $ = 0$

where **F** is a vector field.

Apparently the above follows trivially from the initial statement guaranteed by Clairaut's Theorem, but I don't see how/why it follows. Why does $F$ being conservative guarantee that $\operatorname{curl} F = 0$ ?

Comment: Addendum: how do I bold variables like $F$ in MathJax to indicate that they're vectors?

Comment: The proposition is that if $F$ is conservative, **then** $\text{curl} F=0$, not the converse, although the converse is also true locally.

Comment: Addendum: `\mathbf{F}` (as in "math bold font") yields $\mathbf{F}$.

Comment: @Gribouillis Oops, fixed my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have it the wrong way around. Zero curl doesn't imply conservative without some assumptions on the actual space in question (like if the field is defined and differentiable on *all* of $\Bbb R^3$). But that's another question entirely.

What they're saying is that conservative implies zero curl. Their second statement follows from the first in that if $\mathbf F$ is a conservative field, then there is some $f$ such that $\nabla f = \mathbf F$. Thus $\nabla \times \mathbf F = \nabla\times \nabla f = 0$.

Comment: Could you expound on the limit definition of curl? James Stewart defines it as the cross product of the gradient components and the field in question.

Comment: Also, how does my second statement follow from the first? Apparently it's essentially a restatement, but I don't see the resemblance.

Comment: @TiwaAina I edited in an actual proof of what you're asking about.

Answer (score 1):

As an addendum to Arthur's answer, the reason your text is saying that the conclusion follows from Clairaut's theorem is that if $F$ is conservative, $F = \nabla f$ for some scalar function $f$. To see this, pick an arbitrary point $x_0$ and define
$$f(x) = \int_0^1 \langle F[\gamma(t)], \gamma'(t)\rangle \,dt$$
where $\gamma:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^3$ is an arbitrary smooth curve from $x_0$ to $x$. The definition of a conservative vector field is exactly the condition that this integral is independent of $\gamma$ and that therefore $f$ is well-defined and smooth. Now for any vector $v$, pick a path $\gamma$ that ends with $\gamma'(1) = v$, and you have
$$\langle\nabla f ,v\rangle = \frac{d}{dh} \int_0^{1+h}\langle F[\gamma(t)], \gamma'(t)\rangle \,dt = \langle F(x), v\rangle.$$